# How to I interrogate a forkjoin using an Observable?

Tags: typescript, observable

I am calling a forkjoin to check for the presence of a person on two different independent data stores. I want to take action (perform a delete) when it is not found on either. When the action occurs it should return true, otherwise false. However as I have coded it up, the subscribe in the calling method does not get signaled when the true fires.

How do I restructure the method and how it is called so that it receives the 'true' signal?

This is the calling code (at the component level):

```
    deletePerson(person: PersonMasterBase) {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete person: ' + person.p_PersonID + '?',
            header: 'Confirm',
            icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
            accept: () => {
                this.model.deletePerson(person.p_PersonID, this.persons).subscribe((result) => 
                {
                    if (result)
                    {
                        this.persons = this.persons.filter(val => val.p_PersonID !== person.p_PersonID);
                        this.person = new PersonMasterBase;
                        this.isChanged = true;
                        this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Person Deleted', life: 3000});
                    }
               });
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the method in question (In the repository):

```
    deletePerson(id: number, allPersons : PersonMasterBase[]): Observable<boolean> {
        let personISPassenger: Object;
        let personISUser : Object;
        let passengerCheck = this.dataSource.getEntryInUseById<PassengerMasterBase[]>("/Passenger/PersonInUse", "PersonID", id);
        let userCheck = this.dataSource.getEntryInUseById<UserMasterBase[]>("/User/PersonInUse", "PersonID", id);


        forkJoin([passengerCheck, userCheck]).subscribe(results => {
            personISPassenger= results[0];
            personISUser= results[1];
            let logString: string = `Person ${id} is in use as a passenger or a user.`;
            if (personISUser || personISPassenger)
            {
                this.dialogService.openModalOk("Delete Person Rejected",logString, ()=>{
                //confirmed
                    console.log(logString);
                });
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                let index = allPersons.findIndex(p => this.locator(p, id));
                if (index > -1) {
                    this.deletedPersons.push(allPersons[index]);
                    allPersons.splice(index, 1);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        return of(false);
    }
```

Comment: returning values inside subscribe just doesn't look correct. Perhaps you could pipe the result and map() it to either true or false.

Comment: I'm learning as I go with this. I could try that.

Comment: Also a pro tip: always make sure you don't give forkJoin an empty array, or it will never complete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `subscribe` of the `forkJoin` you create an unnamed arrow function which is executed when both `passengerCheck` and `userCheck` complete. In this function you have various returns. These returns are for the unnamed arrow function and **not** the `deletePerson` function.

So basically, nothing happens in there. What you have to do is return the `Observable` that is returned by the `forkJoin` after you map the results to a boolean:

```
deletePerson(id: number, allPersons : PersonMasterBase[]): Observable<boolean> {
    let personISPassenger: Object;
    let personISUser : Object;
    let passengerCheck = this.dataSource.getEntryInUseById<PassengerMasterBase[]>("/Passenger/PersonInUse", "PersonID", id);
    let userCheck = this.dataSource.getEntryInUseById<UserMasterBase[]>("/User/PersonInUse", "PersonID", id);


    return forkJoin([passengerCheck, userCheck]).pipe(map((results => {
        personISPassenger= results[0];
        personISUser= results[1];
        let logString: string = `Person ${id} is in use as a passenger or a user.`;
        if (personISUser || personISPassenger)
        {
            this.dialogService.openModalOk("Delete Person Rejected",logString, ()=>{
            //confirmed
                console.log(logString);
            });
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            let index = allPersons.findIndex(p => this.locator(p, id));
            if (index > -1) {
                this.deletedPersons.push(allPersons[index]);
                allPersons.splice(index, 1);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I tried something like this but could not quite get the syntax correct.